# I wnt to run JavaHelp both from IDE and jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, git, javahelp

I have an application (DrawFBP) which has a Help facility. built using JavaHelp.  I actually had it working for several years on the Eclipse IDE, but I had never tested it running in the jar file.  The Help facility uses a number of html files, and some other stuff, and one informant said I can get them included on the jar file by putting them in a resources folder (src/main/resources) .  This seems to have worked!  After lots of restructuring, I got my Help facility working on the jar file, but it stopped working on the IDE.  The IDE version is crashing on a FileNotFoundException referencing a file with extra levels of qualification - where do they come from?  I am probably making several dumb errors - but help would be much appreciated!  The project can be found on GitHub - https://github.com/jpaulm/drawfbp .  The code and resources are there, but Git wants me to add all my code back in again - not sure why... TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow got it working - the trick seems to be to include the resources in a folder called 'resources' under src/main.  I will accept this answer - unless someone comes up with a better one!